# How can I zip each file separately instead of putting in one archive?

Tags: ant

I have 3 files (eg: m1.txt, m2.txt and m3.txt) in my /tmp/ folder. How can I zip each files as m1.zip, m2.zip and m3.zip?

I used the following coding, but didn't work:

```
<target name="xzipit">
   <foreach target="zipone" param="Files"> 
      <path> 
         <fileset dir="/tmp/" excludes="*.zip"  
                  includes="*.txt" casesensitive="no" />
      </path>
   </foreach>
</target>

<target name="zipone">
   <zip destfile="${Files}" basedir="/tmp/">
   </zip>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note use of `fileset` **id**, **refid** usage below and also on specifying **includesfile** to `zip` ant task

```
    <fileset dir="/tmp" excludes="*.zip"  includes="*.txt" id="zip.fileset.id" casesensitive="no" />

    <pathconvert property="zipFileSetProp" refid="zip.fileset.id">
        <mapper>
            <flattenmapper/>
        </mapper>
    </pathconvert>

    <for list="${zipFileSetProp}" param="fileToZip" delimiter=";">
        <sequential>
            <echo>fileToZip @{fileToZip}</echo>
            <zip destfile="/tmp/@{fileToZip}.zip" basedir="/tmp/" includesfile="/tmp/@{fileToZip}"/>
        </sequential>
    </for>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got one more answer to solve this.

```
<project name="texzip" basedir="." default="zipit">

   <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="/tmp/ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
     </classpath>
   </taskdef>

   <target name="zipit">
     <foreach target="zipone" param="Files">
       <path>
         <fileset dir="/tmp/" excludes="*.zip" includes="*.txt" casesensitive="no" />
       </path>
     </foreach>
   </target>

   <target name="zipone">
     <basename property="basename" file="${Files}" suffix="txt"/>
       <zip destfile="${basename}.zip">
       <zipfileset dir="." includes="${basename}.txt"/>
       </zip>
   </target>
</project>
```